# Shrink node_modules directory?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, proguard, shrink

I've used [proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage) to [shrink android app packages](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) before. It removes unused classes and files from app dependencies, even 3rd party ones, resulting in considerably lower package size. Is there an equivalent in node/npm ?

`npm prune --production` removes dev dependencies, and [node-prune](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-prune) partially removes unused files. But neither completely remove unnecessary code from within a 3rd party package.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Completely accurate static analysis of what exactly is needed in a 3rd party module is not entirely possible as functions, files or modules can be referenced dynamically depending upon the circumstances of usage or platforms run on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already mention the `--production` flag and `node-prune` in your question, so I'll leave those out. (You can also look at [`dmn`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dmn) which is similar to `node-prune`.)

If you are using a bundler like `rollup` or `webpack`, they can do [tree](https://github.com/rollup/rollup#tree-shaking) [shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) to remove code you're not using. (I'm not sure how much configuration is required to get it to safely work with a third-party module in `node_modules` or even if that's possible.) In this case, tree shaking wouldn't remove the code from `node_modules` though. Instead, these tools bundle everything into a single executable file and remove the unused code from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove it completely, `node_modules` is needed to run your script.
And you may think there are unused files but they're still needed in some cases.

So let's check it carefully when doing such things.
If the total file size is your matter. I recommend to use this tool:
https://github.com/tj/node-prune

It gives you some options to control which to remove or not.